# com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool when trying to setup HikraCP with Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, driver, amazon-redshift, hikaricp

I'm trying to setup a JDBC Connection Pool using HikariCP with AWS Redshift like this:

```
public class RedshiftConnector {

private static HikariDataSource dataSource;
private static int poolSize = 5;

public static void init() throws SQLException {

    dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setDataSource(new com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.DataSource());
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(Parameters.REDSHIFT_DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(Parameters.REDSHIFT_DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(Parameters.REDSHIFT_DB_PASSWORD);
    dataSource.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(poolSize);
}

public static synchronized Connection getConnection() {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}

public static void close() {
    dataSource.close();
}
}
```

I have added the JAR for Redshift Driver on the classpath!

Now the problem is when I call `RedshiftConnector.getConnection()` I get the following error:

```
[com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Error creating Driver, Driver class name incorrect.] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver cannot be cast to com.amazon.dsi.core.interfaces.IDriver
    at com.amazon.dsi.core.impl.DSIDriverFactory.createDriver(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.doInitialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getSimbaConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:316)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:94)
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like either a bug in that redshift driver (specifically `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver cannot be cast to com.amazon.dsi.core.interfaces.IDriver`), or maybe you have inconsistent library versions on your classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this:

Instead of using **setDataSource()**:

```
dataSource.setDataSource(new com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.DataSource());
```

we had to use **setDriverClassName()** and works perfect with AWS Redshift:

```
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
```

Thanks

Comment: You also need to mention that jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName, which isn't with setDataSource